# What is the difference between these two methods for checking if a number is a prime?

Tags: java, return

I wrote a method for checking if a number is a prime:

```
static boolean isPrime(int x) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(x); i++) {
            if (x % i == 0)
                return false;    
        }
        return true;
    }
```

In a collection of exercises we're learning from, the solution is:

```
static boolean isPrime(int x) {
    boolean hasDivisors = false;
    for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(x); i++) {
      if (x % i == 0) {
        hasDivisors = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    return !hasDivisors;
}
```

In my case, If i find a divisor, I return that the number is not a prime (`return false`) and that replaces the need for a `break` in second method. The only other obvious reason is that the second method only uses a single `return` statement.

Is there a reason for this (speed/memory wise)?

Comment: The second method is much more readable and easy to understand. Performance wise, both methods are same.

Comment: No. It's just a matter of style.

Comment: The only difference is that the official solution is a tad bit easier to comprehent for beginners. As far as I see there is no real difference in runtime or memory consumption.

Comment: I actually prefer the first method. The second looks unnecessarily bloated. Early exits can be confusing in large functions, but I think in small functions it's more readable. Whenever I've written a naive prime-finding function, it almost always looks like your version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both solutions work and both are valid for all the reasons you have already identified. Good analysis. As others have noted, the differences are purely stylistic. Here is an [interesting discussion about the single return statement style in java](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118703/where-did-the-notion-of-one-return-only-come-from).

Performance-wise, I wouldn't expect a significant difference between the 2 approaches. But if you want to be certain, perform a benchmark test. If you want a real performance boost, you can eliminate the expensive call to `Math.sqrt()` by replacing:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(x); i++) {
```

with

```
for (int i = 2; i*i <= x; i++) {
```

Comment: Or call sqrt once outside the loop and cache the result to get even faster. Still no match to state-of-the art prime testers, though ^^

Answer (score 5):

It's a matter of style, mostly. Some coding conventions dictate that a method have only a single `return` statement. This makes a lot of sense in languages where you have to free resources explicitly, but doesn't have any functional impact in Java.

Personally, I prefer to just `return` as soon as you know the result (like in the first snippet), but again, it's a matter of personal style.