# The method must return a type int

Tags: java, function, return

```
public int computeStyle(String season) {
    if(season.equals("summer")){
        if (this.style.equals("toque")){
            return 8;
        }
        if (this.style.equals("sun visor")){
            return 1;
        }
        if (this.style.equals("fedora")){
            return 6;
        }
    }
    else if(season.equals("winter")){
        if (this.style.equals("toque")){
            return 1;
        }
        if (this.style.equals("sun visor")){
            return 8;
        }
        if (this.style.equals("fedora")){
            return 7;
        }
    }
    else return 5;
}
```

Why do I keep getting the error that the method must return type int. What is wrong with this function? It should return an int in every possible scenario right?

Answer (score 6):

There are two paths that are not covered:

```
public int computeStyle(String season) {
    if(season.equals("summer")){
        if (this.style.equals("toque")){
            return 8;
        }
        if (this.style.equals("sun visor")){
            return 1;
        }
        if (this.style.equals("fedora")){
            return 6;
        }
        //here
    }
    else if(season.equals("winter")){
        if (this.style.equals("toque")){
            return 1;
        }
        if (this.style.equals("sun visor")){
            return 8;
        }
        if (this.style.equals("fedora")){
            return 7;
        }
        //here
    }
    else return 5;
}
```

Solution: declare a variable with the defaut return value and assign the value properly:

```
public int computeStyle(String season) {
    int result = 5;
    if(season.equals("summer")){
        if (this.style.equals("toque")){
            result = 8;
        }
        if (this.style.equals("sun visor")){
            result = 1;
        }
        if (this.style.equals("fedora")){
            result = 6;
        }
    }
    else if(season.equals("winter")){
        if (this.style.equals("toque")){
            result = 1;
        }
        if (this.style.equals("sun visor")){
            result = 8;
        }
        if (this.style.equals("fedora")){
            result = 7;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: or you can simply replace `else return 5;` with `return 5;`

Comment: @Asaph or stop this nonsense and use a single point of return instead of having several `return` statements. Also, the code can be refactored to be more readable and easier to maintan, but that's outside the scope of this Q/A.

Comment: Funny. I was just discussing that very issue moments ago in http://stackoverflow.com/q/30290577 . Feel free to weigh in there with an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If your return type is int, any how your method must return an int.

In this case inside your outer `if else`, you still have `if` blocks, means if, inside the outer `if else`, if non if the condition is satisfied, then it ll return nothing.

In this case, you should always add a return statement at the end.

Like this :

```
public int computeStyle(String season) {
    if(season.equals("summer")){
        if (this.style.equals("toque")){
            return 8;
        }
        if (this.style.equals("sun visor")){
            return 1;
        }
        if (this.style.equals("fedora")){
            return 6;
        }
    }
    else if(season.equals("winter")){
        if (this.style.equals("toque")){
            return 1;
        }
        if (this.style.equals("sun visor")){
            return 8;
        }
        if (this.style.equals("fedora")){
            return 7;
        }
    }
    else return 5;

   // If everything fails, then it ll return 0 at least
   return 0;
}
```